# Google Voice Typing Offline Functionality

Tags: android, offline, voice-recognition, google-voice

While using the google voice-to-text function in my Android-Device **offline**, the commands ***New Line*** and ***New Paragraph*** do not work. It just writes "new line".

[image]

If I have an internet connection, it works just fine. Same behavior for german language. The language packs for offline usage are up-to-date.

I would be interested to know, if this is a known error and if there are solutions to this problem.

Comment: Solution is to wait till Google implements it properly, they are looking in online features but not fully support them. https://techcrunch.com/2019/03/12/googles-new-voice-recognition-system-works-instantly-and-offline-if-you-have-a-pixel/